Ollama - How to inject context or get model to answer based on context?
I'm trying a simple demo where I give the LLM a document and ask it to answer a few things from the document. So far I've had very little success.
My prompt is various versions of the following:

You are an uncensored and unbiased AI assistant for question answering tasks. Use the provided context to answer the question. If the answer is not present in the context, refrain from providing an answer based on your own knowledge. Instead, indicate that relevant information is not available. Only use the following context:

I've tried:

Adding document text  to the start of the user query. E.g. Context: [A LOT OF TEXT]\n\n Question: [A QUESTION ABOUT THE TEXT]
Adding document text  to the start of the user query as XML. E.g. <Context>[A LOT OF TEXT]</Context>\n\n <Question>[A QUESTION ABOUT THE TEXT]</Question>
Adding document text in the system prompt (ie. specifying SYSTEM var) via custom model file. E.g., ollama create phi3_custom -f CustomModelFile
Also added document text via system parameter when using Ollama's /api/generate API endpoint
Changing the temperature via custom model file

My test is quite simple. A smallish file (~4000 words) with simple questions like who is the author and other specific, relatively simple questions. But neither Llama3 nor Phi3 gets it quite right. I've had a lot of success with the OpenHermes model by just adding the context along with the user query.
So my question is:
If I have a simple document (just text), that fits into the context window, how do I get the LLM to answer my questions?
Extra info:

I'm using Ollama (both via the CLI and the http API through python)
Using the same prompt + context through Claude, GPT3.5, GPT4o works as expected. So I don't think the issue is my prompting?
Hardware is quite limited, M1 Mac with 8GB RAM (hence interests in Phi3!)

Any suggestions to get the LLM to obey my command / see/utilise the context?

I seem to get better answers now by adding my text to the system parameter when using the /api/generate endpoint. I did try this previously, but it didn't seem to work. However, it works now. ¯\(ツ)/¯

It sounds like the question is "how do you prompt Ollama with context?" Here's an example prompt that I tested against Ollama and worked well from Langchain - Prompt is here. You can see the code here with metrics (just change the LLM to Ollama from GPT): https://github.com/explodinggradients/ragas/issues/1217.

Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try
to make up an answer.
economy in the world. New York City is an established safe haven for
global investors. New York is home to the highest number of
billionaires, individuals of ultra-high net worth (greater than US$30
million), and millionaires of any city in the world.
busiest pedestrian intersections and a major center of the world's
entertainment industry. Many of the city's landmarks, skyscrapers, and
parks are known around the world, and the city's fast pace led to the
phrase New York minute. The Empire State Building is a global standard
of reference to describe the height and length of other
structures.Manhattan's real estate market is among the most expensive
in the world. Providing continuous 24/7 service and contributing to
the nickname The City That
The city and its metropolitan area constitute the premier gateway for
legal immigration to the United States. As many as 800 languages are
spoken in New York, making it the most linguistically diverse city in
the world. New York City is home to more than 3.2 million residents
born outside the U.S., the largest foreign-born population of any city
in the world as of 2016.New York City traces its origins to a trading
post founded on the southern tip of Manhattan Island by Dutch
colonists in
approximately 1624. The settlement was named New Amsterdam (Dutch:
Nieuw Amsterdam) in 1626 and was chartered as a city in 1653. The city
came under British control in 1664 and was renamed New York after King
Charles II of England granted the lands to his brother, the Duke of
York. The city was regained by the Dutch in July 1673 and was renamed
New Orange for one year and three months; the city has been
continuously named New York since November 1674. New York City was the
capital of the United
Question: What is the economic significance of New York City? Helpful
Answer:New York City is a safe haven for global investors, home to the
highest number of billionaires and millionaires, and has an extremely
expensive real estate market, making it one of the most economically
significant cities in the world. It also serves as the premier gateway
for legal immigration to the United States, with over 3.2 million
residents born outside the U.S., which contributes to its economic
diversity and growth.

Here's sample code
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_ollama.llms import OllamaLLM

context_str='''
economy in the world. New York City is an established safe haven for global investors. New York is home to the highest number of billionaires, individuals of ultra-high net worth (greater than US$30 million), and millionaires of any city in the world.
busiest pedestrian intersections and a major center of the world's entertainment industry. Many of the city's landmarks, skyscrapers, and parks are known around the world, and the city's fast pace led to the phrase New York minute. The Empire State Building is a global standard of reference to describe the height and length of other structures.Manhattan's real estate market is among the most expensive in the world. Providing continuous 24/7 service and contributing to the nickname The City That
The city and its metropolitan area constitute the premier gateway for legal immigration to the United States. As many as 800 languages are spoken in New York, making it the most linguistically diverse city in the world. New York City is home to more than 3.2 million residents born outside the U.S., the largest foreign-born population of any city in the world as of 2016.New York City traces its origins to a trading post founded on the southern tip of Manhattan Island by Dutch colonists in
approximately 1624. The settlement was named New Amsterdam (Dutch: Nieuw Amsterdam) in 1626 and was chartered as a city in 1653. The city came under British control in 1664 and was renamed New York after King Charles II of England granted the lands to his brother, the Duke of York. The city was regained by the Dutch in July 1673 and was renamed New Orange for one year and three months; the city has been continuously named New York since November 1674. New York City was the capital of the United
'''
template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.\n\n{context}\n\nQuestion: {question}\nHelpful Answer:"""

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)

model = OllamaLLM(model="llama3.1")

chain = prompt | model

print(chain.invoke({"question":"What is the economic significance of New York City?","context": context_str}))

